# Pointer to a pointer in C not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning pointers in C. I have a 2D array of integers and I'm trying to add all the elements in a single row. The 2D array name is `a`. I know that `a` is a pointer to the array rows, which are themselves pointers to integer elements. I want to loop over the entire array `a`. So, I declared a pointer `**pp` to be equal to `a`, since `a` is a pointer to a pointer. But the program is crashing at run time.

```
int main(void){
int sum=0;
int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int **pp = NULL;
int *p = NULL;

for (pp=a;pp<a+3;pp++){
    for (p=*pp;p<*pp+3;p++)
        sum += *p;

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    sum = 0;
    }
}
```

I know that the address of the first object of the 2D array is simply `a`. The address of the second object is `a+1` and so on. Matrix element `i,j` for example would be `*(*(a+i)+j)`. In order words, if I set my pointer variable `pp` to `(a+i)`, I know that I'm in the i-th row. the address of the first integer element of the i-th row is `*(a+i)`, which is why I made `p=*pp`. So element `(i,0)`  should be `*p` which is the same as `*(*(a+i)+0)`. So, why isn't the code running as it should ?

Comment: I believe your `p<*pp+3` should be `p<*(pp+3)`.

Comment: `int (*)[3]` and `int **` are *not* compatible, regardless of what you may have been led to believe. If `pp=a` doesn't flag a warning on your compiler, turn up your warnings.

Comment: But really, coding like this is a terrible thing to do. Why not just make a simple and obvious `for (i=0;...for(j=0;...sum += a[i][j]` loop, and let the compiler do its job of optimizing it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker : no, this would crash as soon as pp is greater than a. He wrote it correctly

Comment: You're right, now that I look at it. But again, there's no reason at all to code this way. I would never hire someone who wrote code like this.

Comment: Somewhat relevant C-FAQ Entry: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code works as well though it needs a cast :

```
int main(void){
    int sum = 0;
    int a[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int *pp = (int*)a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            sum += *pp;
            pp++;
        }
        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
        sum = 0;
   }
}
```

it is a little an academic example because for this you don't really need pointers at all.
The point is that a is basically the address of the memory where the array begins. So I can cast that first element to a pointer to an int. and all following integers can be reached by doing pp++; it just moves the pointer to the right with the sizeof(int). Like this you basically traverse the multi dimentional array in a linear way.

Comment: An alternate solution is `int *pp = a[0]`; at least there's no casting gymnastics required.

Answer (score 5):

A 2D array is not a pointer to pointer. In general arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. Always [remember](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

> "pointer arithmetic and array indexing [that] are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are different".

`a` is an array of `3` arrays of `3` `int`s. `pp` is a pointer to pointer to `int`. When used in expression, in most cases, arrays converted to **pointer to its first element**. Therefore, in `pp = a;`, `a` is converted to `int (*)[3]` which is incompatible with `pp`'s type `int **`. Declare `pp` as `int (*)[3]`.

```
int (*pp)[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Philip Stuyck's solution.  I'd just like to shed some light on why you seg faulted (I recommend using GDB or some other debugger to help you figure out what is going on with your pointers).

So here is your array, a:

```
(gdb) p &a
$14 = (int (*)[3][3]) 0x7fffffffdb10
(gdb) x/9wd a
0x7fffffffdb10: 1   2   3   4
0x7fffffffdb20: 5   6   7   8
0x7fffffffdb30: 9
```

Your pointer, pp is pointing to a:

```
(gdb) p pp
$15 = (int **) 0x7fffffffdb10
```

When you de-reference pp (which is an int **), you are getting an int *.  On a 64 bit machine, this is 8 bytes, hence the garbage address:

```
(gdb) p *pp
$16 = (int *) 0x200000001
(gdb) p (int) *pp
$17 = 1
```

Thus, when you set p=*pp, then try to de-reference it, you seg fault:

```
(gdb) p p
$18 = (int *) 0x200000001
(gdb) p *p
Cannot access memory at address 0x200000001
```

Comment: Suppose, I had instead decleared all my pointers to be of the datatype `long long` which is of size 8 bytes. Would there have been a problem ?

Comment: It'd still be a problem.  Your variable pp points to a (so it's more like just an int *).  When you say p=*pp, you'd have your pointer p = 1 (rather than p = 0x20000001).  Either way, when you de-reference p, you are telling the machine to read address 1 which will also seg fault.  I really don't think you want a pointer to a pointer in this case like Philip's code example shows.